# Transitioning Jobs

Tags: transition

I am currently working at HSBC and getting paid quite a hefty sum for the level of qualifications I possess. However due to the global corona virus incident, I am in the verge of taking unpaid leave and possibly a lay off scenario. I am now 25 and believe not too old, and I was thinking all my jobs I will eventually look forwards in to the future will be in somewhere in the finance sector. However I currently do not enjoy my job, and was thinking about using this opportunity with the global crisis to transition my job in to joining my family business.

Has anyone in this stack exchange ever transitioned their job from a technical office job to a separate job such as family business where it has nothing to do with your skills?

Comment: What is the family business in?

Comment: As it stands, your question is way too broad and the actual question at the bottom is really not of any relevance. Of course someone in this stack exchange will have moved on from a technical job to something completely different, just as people will have done the opposite.

Comment: "25 and believe not too old" - you're barely older than most graduates, but you've had a few years to discover what type of work you do and don't enjoy. This is the perfect time to try something new.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Has anyone in this stack exchange ever transitioned their job from a
>   technical office job to a separate job such as family business where
>   it has nothing to do with your skills?

Yes, I did.

After a year, I decided that the family business wasn't for me. I went back to a technical office job in a different domain and never looked back.

In retrospect, it was a great learning experience, and my new career was by far the best career move I ever made.